# quick hull algorithm detail

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, convex-hulls

When using quick hull algorithm to find the polytope for half space intersection, we are required to provide an interior point to the solver [qhalf](http://www.qhull.org/html/qhalf.htm).

In other words, providing 
$$Ax \le b$$
is not sufficient for qhalf to compute its vertex representation. From classroom learning, we know $Ax \le b$ is sufficient and we should be able to compute its vertex representation. I would argue that finding an interior point to $Ax \le b$ could be also very difficult. Therefore, does quick hull algorithm really needs an interior point? Or do I miss anything here?

Comment: Perhaps the interior point is only needed to determine which side of the halfplanes are the halfspaces? It appears that "specify coordinates of interior point" is an option, implying that it is not required.

Comment: As a user after I tried, it is not optional... without providing the internal point, the code would report errors saying that no internal point is provided...